# getting list courses of google classroom in vuex

Tags: google-oauth, vuex, google-api-js-client, google-classroom

I hope somebody can point me in the right direction.
I try to migrate an existing firebase project to google classroom.
I don't have any prior experience with the google api and I'm using vuejs (in the quasar framework actually)
In my vuex instance, i want to log in and fetch all the courses the user is registered to.

This is my code

```
FBLogInToClassroomWithFirebase({commit,dispatch}){
    let provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses');
    
    let firebaseAuth = firebaseApp.auth()
    
    firebaseAuth.signInWithPopup(provider).then((result) => {
    
            var credential = result.credential;
            // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
            var token = credential.accessToken;
            
            // The signed-in user info.
            var user = result.user;
            console.log("user",user)
            console.log("token",token)

           var courses = ??????????
                   
            
        })
```

Both user and token get logged.
But from then I'm stuck!!
I don't know how to get a list of the courses.  I can find some references on the docs, but can't figure out how to call them in vuex
I tried several options like axios and gapi, which i both installed.
But i can't find any sample code for this online.
It would be great if someone could show me how to do this.
Maybe somebody knows a plugin that can help??
Any help is appreciated

Comment: I suppose using axios would have solved the problem. dispatch the action from this function to your store. So, yeah the axios part will come inside your action. Can you tell me what you have already tried. And where exactly you want help? creating a Vuex store or fetching data using axios?

Comment: Hi ! Have you taken a look at [Classroom API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/get-started)? Would you like to implement that on your frontend ? Are you using [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/auth#OAuth2Authorizing)?

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: I tried vue-gapi with this code
`
Inloggen() {
     this.$gapi.login()
     this.$gapi.getGapiClient().then((gapi) => {
       gapi.client.load('classroom', 'v1', this.listCourses);
        })
       },
       listCourses() {
         var request = gapi.client.classroom.courses.list({pageSize: 10});
         request.execute((resp) => {
                console.log("courses", resp.courses)
         });
        },
`
end  I was able to get the courses loggin in seperatly.  But i can't seem to combine it with a token from the firebase login.

Comment: sorry for the messy code, but the backticks don't work

Comment: @ShivamKumar   An example on how to fetch the classroom data with axios would be great.  (I'm rather new to axios)

Comment: You don't need a firebase token. You will just need an API Key and Client ID. Have you taken a look at [this quickstart guide for Javascript](https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/js) ? Do you already have a GCP project?

Comment: I've read the quickstart an have a project.  I use the firebase database and storage, so i think i have to use the firebase token in order to let the users log in to both with just one login action.

Comment: As they are different services with different scopes I don't think you can use the firebase token to authorize calendar API as for that you will need an [OAuth 2.0 token](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth#OAuth2Authorizing). Are you able to authorize Google Calendar API requests using the firebase token?

Comment: @Mateo:  thanks for your answer and sorry for the delay.  I've left the path of vue-gapi and classroom and tried to use google app script as an api